# Enable live reloading while working on website using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, web

I want to implement Live Reloading which will try to watch for changes in the front end page UI files and then automatically recompile the Sass and ES6 JS to raw CSS and browser compatible ES5 JS and also refresh the page.

This will allow us to see the changes we make instantly in the browser without having to kill the server and stand it up again.

Is there any configuration to enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get this functionality with [Webpack Hot Module Replacement](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/).

This is a [seed project for React](https://github.com/debiasej/react-webpack-HMR-seed).

Comment: thanks, please mark it as answer if it answered your question